# Reshape matrix by distributing submatrices to third dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, reshape

I have a long `nx3` matrix. For eg, I take a `9x3` matrix

```
A =

 8     9     8
 9     2     9
 2     9     6
 9     9     1
 6     5     8
 1     8     9
 3     2     7
 5     4     7
 9     9     7
```

Now I want it reshaped, (taking successive `3x3` sub-matrix to the next dimension) such that,

```
out(:,:,1) = 
 8     9     8
 9     2     9
 2     9     6
out(:,:,2)
 9     9     1
 6     5     8
 1     8     9
out(:,:,3)
 3     2     7
 5     4     7
 9     9     7
```

I could do this with loops but I wanted to know how to vectorize this process..
Can i do it with `reshape` and `permute` alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`permute`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [**`reshape`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
A = [...
 8     9     8
 9     2     9
 2     9     6
 9     9     1
 6     5     8
 1     8     9
 3     2     7
 5     4     7
 9     9     7
 3     2     7
 5     4     7
 9     9     7]

n = size(A,2);
B = permute( reshape(A.',n,n,[]), [2 1 3]) %'
%// or as suggested by Divakar
%// B = permute( reshape(A,n,n,[]), [1 3 2])
```

---

```
out(:,:,1) =

     8     9     8
     9     2     9
     2     9     6

out(:,:,2) =

     9     9     1
     6     5     8
     1     8     9

out(:,:,3) =

     3     2     7
     5     4     7
     9     9     7

out(:,:,4) =

     3     2     7
     5     4     7
     9     9     7
```

Comment: Nice one, you were a bit faster. I came up with the same solution, though I used `numel(A)/9` for the third dimension, as the OP says he has `nx3` arrays to split.

Comment: @hbaderts yes, one could generalize it, I will include it :) Thanks!

Comment: @hbaderts `numel(A)/9` wouldn't be a good choice, as you need to know the **9** as well. So `size(A,2)` is more direct.

Comment: I know i could do this with `permute` and `reshape`, I tried several ways but didn't make it. I didn't thought of transposing it. Thanks and +1 :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai Actually you can avoid the transpose! :)

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach -

```
N = 3
out = permute(reshape(A,N,size(A,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])
```

This one has the advantage of avoiding the transpose as used in the [other answer by @thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29587302/3293881).

Sample run -

```
A =
     8     9     8
     9     2     9
     2     9     6
     9     9     1
     6     5     8
     1     8     9
     3     2     7
     5     4     7
     9     9     7
out(:,:,1) =
     8     9     8
     9     2     9
     2     9     6
out(:,:,2) =
     9     9     1
     6     5     8
     1     8     9
out(:,:,3) =
     3     2     7
     5     4     7
     9     9     7
```

Comment: This is certainly true. +1 I hope you don't mind, that I included it also to my answer, as the rest is identical.

Comment: Oops, now my comment on the other answer is meaningless LOL, BTW, Thanks for efforts +1 :)

Comment: @thewaywewalk That's good I guess, but I would like to keep this answer as well :)